Google Play rejects my app even after updating Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics 18.4.0. Aid
I'm trying to publish my app on Google Play. I upgraded from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics 18.4.0, but my app keeps getting rejected. The problem persists despite the update. How can I resolve?
Actualicé desde io.fabric.sdk.androidio.fabric.sdk.android:fabricacom.google.firebase:firebasecrashlytics:18.4.0. I already followed the following steps and it is still being rejected
User Data Policy: Violation of User Data Policy
Details
We have reviewed the SDKs used by your application and have detected versions of SDKs that do not comply with the policies. These versions collect persistent device identifiers. Persistent device identifiers should not be linked to other personal or sensitive user data or device identifiers that can be changed.
We recommend that you update the SDK to a policy-compliant version (if your SDK provider offers that option) or remove this SDK.
Fabric io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric: We recommend that you update the SDK to version com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0.
Additionally, follow these steps to update the version of APKs or app bundles:
Upload the modified APK that meets the policies to all channels and disable the APKs that do not comply.
Navigate to the channels (closed, open test, or production) that have the policy issue. Click "Create new version" or "Edit version."
If the version has non-policy app bundles or APKs that are drafts, discard that version.
Otherwise, add the version of the app bundles or APKs that meets the policies.
Make sure the non-compliant version is in the "Not included" section of this version.
Enter the version name and click Save. Once saved, click Review Version. Then launch the 100% version.
If non-compliant versions are published to multiple channels, repeat step 2 for each channel.
In addition to the production version, if you have other types of versions that you use for testing or QA checks (for example, an internal, closed, or open test version), update those channels as well.

Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

Questions asking for customer support with third-party services (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for topics that are valid here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
